# Is better have one huge image or have different size of the same image

Tags: android, image-processing

i mean is better way to have one huge image then resizing by dp in the layout or is better have different size of the same image.thanks i'm pretty new on android design so i hope someone could explain me.

Comment: what is ur usage for the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is better to have an image in multiple sizes since resizing may cause areas of the image to be scaled incorrectly in terms of what you expect/want.  This is the main reason that Android has multiple drawable resource directories.  Additionally, by using multiple images resolutions your application will take up less running memory (RAM) than it would if you were to scale large resolutions for every image.

Answer (score 0):

Different sizes is better. Doing it only once is more efficient than doing it each and every time the app opens up.

However, if you're just doing a prototype, do not worry about that part.